# Отсутствие переводов в окне добавления картинки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, редактор, загрузка-изображения

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Теперь перевод можно самому добавить. https://ru.traducir.win/

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev я и раньше мог :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. https://ru.traducir.win/string/11025

> Вставьте изображение или ссылку:

2. https://ru.traducir.win/string/11024

> $browseStart$Загрузите$browseEnd$, перетащите или $pasteStart$вставьте$pasteEnd$ изображение или ссылку

Comment: А "Browse" чего остался? Халтура! :) Кстати, я почему-то для длинной строки ещё не вижу перевода в традусёре.

Comment: @älёxölüt чо-т традукир не такой удобный, как трансифекс.

Comment: Зато его можно допилить при желании (было бы желание). P.S. теперь "paste" остался. Кажется, кто-то не выспался :)

Comment: @älёxölüt то-то и оно.

Comment: Нужна кнопка "Edit & Approve"!

Comment: @älёxölüt вообще, да. Всем проверенным переводчикам выдать )

Comment: Добавил ещё "(максимум 2Мб)" и утвердил всё.